# How can I start workflow for files uploaded programmatically

Tags: workflow, liferay, liferay-6, document-library

Can I start the workflow for a file uploaded in document and library of liferay?

Here is my code:

```
DLFolder dlFolder = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 0, "Test");
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(DLFileEntry.class.getName(),
actionRequest);

fileEntry = DLFileEntryServiceUtil.addFileEntry(dlFolder.getGroupId(), dlFolder.getRepositoryId(), dlFolder.getFolderId() ,file.getName(),"" ,title,"test", null, dlFolder.getDefaultFileEntryTypeId(), null, file, null, file.getUsableSpace(), serviceContext);
```

//********************************************************************NOW**************************************************

- How can I start the workflow for the file which has been uploaded?
- The started workflow, will it be the same workflow for all files in the test folder?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear.

If you are talking about whether Liferay's workflow will get applied when you upload documents programatically? Then answer would be yes provided you have selected workflow definition for document library portlet.

You will find workflow task in the control panel under My workflow Tasks.

Comment: yes the question is this.
Can I know how do? (to code)
please.

Comment: I have just selected workflow definition for document library portlet, but will not start when I add a file programmatically using this code, adds it to the folder as a draft, not as pending.

Comment: if i am not wrong u created a custom portlet of file upload..and u want to start workflow as soon as file is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a custom portlet and the folder into which you're trying to upload a document has workflow,

```
DLFolder dlFolder = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 0, "Test");
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(DLFileEntry.class.getName(),
actionRequest);

FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
DLFileEntry fileEntry = DLFileEntryServiceUtil.addFileEntry(dlFolder.getGroupId(), dlFolder.getRepositoryId(), dlFolder.getFolderId() ,
                            file.getName(),MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file) ,title,"test", StringPool.BLANK, 
                            dlFolder.getDefaultFileEntryTypeId(), null, file, is,
                            file.length(), serviceContext);
DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(userId, fileEntry.getFileEntryId(), file.getName(), MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file), 
        title(), "test", StringPool.BLANK, Boolean.FALSE, dlFileEntry.getFileEntryTypeId(), null, file, is,
        file.length(), serviceContext)
```

You should call **updateFilEntry** method after **addFileEntry**. It actually does two things,

1. It changes the state of the document from **Draft**
2. It invokes **workflow**

Hope this helps.